# PHP Creating folder with the owner as 99

Tags: php, directory, chmod, chown, file-ownership

I have a script (run as a cron) that creates a new folder called `images` on a server and moves images from the root folder to this new folder. Later another function will create thumbnails from these images and places these into another new folder named `thumbs` inside that same folder.

However, this function will only work if the parenting `images` folder has the owner set to 99 for some strange reason. The folder gets the user as its default owner.

How can I get the script to create a folder with the owner set to 99? Or what could be the reason that the PHP script has no power of chmod-ing files that have the user as the owner?

Comment: Is the cron running a php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it depends on how the php script was run in the cronjob to determine which owner will be set as the default on newly created files.

First I used:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/script.php > /home/username/public_html/file.xml 2>&1
```

But this created new folders with the owner set to the 'username'.

Instead using curl:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s http://domain.com/script.php > /home/username/public_html/file.xml 2>&1
```

Allowed the new files/folders to be created with the owner set to `nobody` (UID 99) which in its turn allowed the next script to create new folders/files inside this folder without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The cron job is running as `nobody` (UID 99), so that user must have the appropriate permissions. You will need to have the cron job run as a different user if you don't want to change the permissions.